# Deep clone Object does not run function - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clone an Object that is frozen with npm deep-freeze, but the function will not run itself again.

I have tried to run the `if(typeof === "object")`, followed by `Object.assign`, but this gives me the

> typeError: Cannot assign to read only property

```
function updateTree(tree, id, values) {
  const treeData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tree));
  const dataKeys = Object.keys(tree[id]);

  for (let property in treeData) {
    if (property === treeData[id].id) {
      dataKeys.forEach(key =>
        key in values ? Object.assign(treeData[id], values) : null
      );

      if (treeData[id].children.length >= 1) {
        treeData[id].children.map(childId =>
          updateTree(treeData, childId, values)
        );
      }
    }
  }
  return treeData;
}
```

```
test("update child nodes", t => {
      const tree = freeze({
        "1": {
          id: "1",
          foo: "",
          baz: "",
          children: ["2", "3"]
        },
        "2": {
          id: "2",
          foo: "",
          baz: "",
          children: ["4", "5"]
        },
        "3": {
          id: "3",
          foo: "",
          baz: "",
          children: ["6"]
        },
        "4": {
          id: "4",
          foo: "",
          baz: "",
          children: ["7"]
        },
        "5": {
          id: "5",
          foo: "",
          baz: "",
          children: []
        },
        "6": {
          id: "6",
          foo: "",
          baz: "",
          children: []
        },
        "7": {
          id: "7",
          foo: "",
          baz: "",
          children: []
        }
      });


      updateTree(tree, "2", {
        foo: "bar",
        baz: "qux"
      })
```

The expected result is for the function updateTree() to run so the function is recursive

```
updateTree(treeData, childId, values)
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tree))` - oh the naive copy, oh the futility...

Comment: @user633183 probably trying to remove all the function and undefined keys?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the code you posted. You never assign to something that has readonly properties? Also maybe you should start over. Your code does really weird things (like that `key in values ? …`, or the `map` call whose result is thrown away).

Comment: You mentioned npm deep-freeze like it's central to the problem. You probably need to show that code.